# Contradictions and misunderstandings

Tags: textual-discrepancies, judgment

{EDIT:

THE QUESTION:

Is there scripture supporting right wing Christians condemning homosexuality or any other sin in the New Testament.

}

Why so right wing Christians say what is and isn't a sin when it is said in scripture

James 4:12
There is only one Lawgiver and Judge, the one who is able to save and destroy. But you--who are you to judge your neighbor?

Ins't James saying its gods law so only he knows whats sin and whats not?

Jesus says
Matthew 22:39-40
 39"The second is like it, 'YOU SHALL LOVE YOUR NEIGHBOR AS YOURSELF.' 40"On these two commandments depend the whole Law and the Prophets."

Is he not saying here. As long as you put love in all your actions you can't sin?

I guess this is not a question like it should be so I will ask.

Is there any scripture that proves Christians don't misunderstand this that is new testament?

Comment: I think your question will need a total rewrite. I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Christians are to proclaim the message God gave them. That message includes telling people what is sinful. Not judging means not saying that people are beyond hope of salvation.

Comment: My question is. Is there scripture that supports christians condemning homosexuality in the new testament

Comment: @alekblank We have lots of questions about that already, so please search for them first.

Comment: Your edit reads "homosexuality *or any other sin*". Your comment specifically says "homosexuality". Which are you interested in?

Answer (score 2):

I read your question and it seems as if you are saying that because we are under grace, the law does not matter.  I actually used to believe this.  That is how people justify what I would call "human or secular" behavior. The person that is under grace (NT) got there because of the law (OT). God gave us a way out of the law, because he knew we could not keep the law. A sin is a sin.  Christians should condemn what according to the Bible (OT and NT)is a sin. This does not mean we hate the SINNER. Because we have all sinned and fallen short of God's glory. No one has led a sinless life (except Jesus). We are all filthy rotten disgusting sinners . Now you asked about James 4:12. 
James 4:12King James Version (KJV) 12 There is one lawgiver, who is able to save and to destroy: who art thou that judgest another? God will have the final judgement over the unsaved, you are not to speak evil of one another.  But a truly saved person will follow James 4:8 8 Draw nigh to God, and he will draw nigh to you. Cleanse your hands, ye sinners; and purify your hearts, ye double minded.  Cleanse yourself of unrighteousness. Purify your heart.  God gave us the law in the Bible and in our hearts. We know the law but can't obey, that is why we are in need of grace. And the law says that homosexuality as well as many other things are a sin. As the poster stated above there are many verses that expound on the topic of homosexuality.  The bible clarifies itself and interprets itself. You have to take the Bible as a WHOLE, you can't pick and choose.  IF you do then it is no longer the sacred word of God Almighty, it is just a collection of old writings by shepherds, publicans and Pharisees.